# Rails: Wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, rails-admin

I'm trying to open my MongoDB models, however, I'm getting the following error:

`MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.find | FAILED | wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) | 0.013306s`

My Mongo credentials are correct, and I can connect to the database's collections outside of Rails.

The first few lines of the error are:

```
Started GET "/admin/xsl_sheet" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2020-03-03 13:49:54 UTC
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"model_name"=>"xsl_sheet"}
(5.0ms)  SELECT `companies`.`name` FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT `companies`.`name` FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4  [["id", "4"]]
CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT `companies`.`name` FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 4  [["id", "4"]]

MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslStart | STARTED | {}
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslStart | SUCCEEDED | 0.007s
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslContinue | STARTED | {}
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslContinue | SUCCEEDED | 0.006s
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslContinue | STARTED | {}
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.saslContinue | SUCCEEDED | 0.006s
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"TestCompanyNumber2_xsl_sheets", "filter"=>{"assetable_id"=>4}, "limit"=>1, "skip"=>0, "sort"=>{"_id"=>-1}, "projection"=>{"_id"=>1}}
MONGODB | xxx.xx.x.xxx:27017 | db.find | FAILED | wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) | 0.013306s
Rendered /Project/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml within 
    layouts/rails_admin/application (349.7ms)
    Rendered public/500.html (64.4ms)
    wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
    /GEMS/gems/bson-4.8.0-java/lib/bson/hash.rb:115:in `from_bson'
```

Edit:

Here is the code inside rails_admin.rb which (I believe) is in charge of pulling objects from MongoDB:

```
c.model XslSheet do
  label Proc.new {"Xsl Sheet"}
  navigation_label Proc.new {I18n.t('navigation.actions')}
  weight 303
  navigation_icon 'fa fa-file-excel-o'
  list do
    scopes [:applicationId]
    field :data_file_name
    field :updated_at
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please share the actual code in the controller, which is performing the `find`?

Comment: @pcrglennon I've added what pulls information from Mongo from rails admin

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't realize at first this was through rails-admin (though now that I look through the stack trace, I should have known!). I'm sorry but I'm stumped as well, not familiar with how rails-admin does things. I added that tag (rails-admin) to the question, hopefully that will help people who know more about that see this question.

Comment: That error message is calling out [this line](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/v4.8.0/lib/bson/hash.rb#L115), which is attempted to deserialize the response.  Perhaps the response from the server was an error?

Comment: @pcrglennon Ah ok, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-2146. Downgrade to bson 4.7.0 until 4.8.2 is released.

To help people answer your questions, include the versions of the software you are using (in this case, `mongoid`, `mongo` and `bson` versions are relevant), as well as the fact you are using JRuby.